# How to give propertyList a name via variable in CLISP?

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

Let my code be:

```
(defun ct (x) 
                (setq x '(  (man noun singular)
                    (woman noun singular)
                    (likes verb singular)
                    (a article)
                    (man verbIplural)
                )
    )
)
```

if i call it like `(ct '(myplist))`
it won't work how can I fix this?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? what does "won't work" mean? please specify what you want and what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
CL-USER 20 > (defun ct (symbol) 
               (set symbol '((man noun singular)
                             (woman noun singular)
                             (likes verb singular)
                             (a article)
                             (man verbIplural))))
CT

CL-USER 21 > (ct 'myplist)
((MAN NOUN SINGULAR) (WOMAN NOUN SINGULAR)
 (LIKES VERB SINGULAR) (A ARTICLE) (MAN VERBIPLURAL))

CL-USER 22 > myplist
((MAN NOUN SINGULAR) (WOMAN NOUN SINGULAR)
 (LIKES VERB SINGULAR) (A ARTICLE) (MAN VERBIPLURAL))
```

In Lisp that list is not really a *property list*, but an *assoc list*.